# Clojure change object item

Tags: arrays, object, vector, clojure

I am  new in Clojure. I need found the item in file, change value and save, but I cant change value. I need make a new copy of array?

File:

```
{:name "John", :index 0}
{:name "Ivan", :index 1}
{:name "Niki", :index 2}
```

Code:

```
(ns test1.core
  (:gen-class))

(use 'clojure.java.io)
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(def file-data "names.txt")

(def findName "Ivan")

(defn write-data[xs, file]
  (with-open [wrtr (writer file)]
       (doall (map #(.write wrtr (str % "\n")) xs))))

(defn read-data[file]
  (with-open [rdr (reader file)]
       (doall (map #(load-string %) (line-seq rdr)))))


(defn -main []

  (def data (read-data file-data))

  (doseq [line data]
    (if (= (line :name) findName)
      (update-in line [:index] inc)
        (println "No")))
  (println data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not changing `data` in any way, which is good because it is immutable and can't be changed anyway. Try wrapping a a call to `write-data` around your `update-in` form.

One small thing as well: `data` should go outside of `-main`.